# How is the inherited file descritor vulnerability dealt with in Unices?

Tags: kernel, security, file-descriptors, fork

Ulrich Drepper [describes a vulnerability](http://udrepper.livejournal.com/20407.html?nojs=1) in programs that have open file descriptors then they `fork()` and `execve()` without lots of very careful locking in place. He also talks about new kernel additions to fix this problem in Linux.

How is this dealt with on other systems?

Answer (score 1):

On systems that don't have close-on-exec, the hard way. The FDs are closed after `fork(3p)` but before `exec(3p)`.

Comment: That makes sense, although just having close-on-exec doesn't fix the problem: you have to have the ability to request that flag from every function that returns a new file descriptor.